# Restoring state when coming back to nested viewpager causes crash

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmentmanager

I have a button that adds the **ParentFragment**. Inside theres a **Viewpager** containing two **ListFragments**. The first time adding the ParentFragment, everything works fine, except when I press back and add the ParentFragment again. The ParentFragment gets created as usual but when it tries to create the Viewpager it somehow crashes the application.

```
                                      ParentFragment
                                           |
                                           V
                    ListFragment 1 <-- Viewpager --> ListFragment 2
```

**Error log:**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: at.umoser.fab.musikbox, PID: 16900
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.util.ArrayList.size()' on a null object reference
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.getFragment(FragmentManager.java:667)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.restoreState(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:211)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onRestoreInstanceState(ViewPager.java:1319)
at android.view.View.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(View.java:13639)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2889)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2895)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2895)
at android.view.View.restoreHierarchyState(View.java:13617)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.restoreViewState(Fragment.java:468)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1094)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1613)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
```

This is how I call the **Viewpager** using **getChildFragmentManager()** in the 'ParentFragment**:

```
mPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pager);
mPagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), connection);
mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
```

Apparently using getChildFragmentManager() instead of using getFragmentManager() is the right way for nested fragments, although the app doesn't crash when using getFragmentManager(), the viewpager simply doesn't appear at all.

Does the Viewpager or its Adapter call the **onRestoreInstanceState**/**restoreState** Methods (check Error Log) everytime its created, or does this happen only in the second time the ParentFragment is added?

If so, how can I force it to create everything from scratch instead of restoring the state? Or is there another solution.

Answer (score 4):

I avoided the state being restored by using `FragmentPagerAdapter` instead of `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` for my Viewpager Adapter. I used the Android docs for the creation of the adapter and missed there were multiple Pager Adapters... so dumb.